# WordPress emails translate to French

Tags: localization

My client's site is in French and we want to translate the canned emails (such as user registration and password lost) to French.  What are the hooks/filters for these?  The default language is french, i.e.

```
define('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');
```

Comment: Actually as soon as I upgraded to 3.6.1 after I posted this, I did select the French version and bam it was there.  Thank you.

Comment: @JMau as an answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He just need to get [French Version of WordPress](http://fr.wordpress.org/)